# Can't receive email from linode rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, production-environment, linode

I am deploying a rails app on Linode.

Something is strange here. I setup gmail for email (e.g., welcome email). If I use my personal email to register, I can receive email properly. But if I use my company's email to register, I can't receive (not even in junk email).

I checked the gmail account (which sends the email). It turns out that gmail has sent all the email properly (I can see all of them in Sent Mail).

Then I have a try on my local machine's development environment. My company's email account can receive the welcome email.

It looks to me that 1. the email setup in promotion mode is ok. At least my personal account, e.g. gmail, hotmail can receive welcome email. 2. my company's email sever allows incoming gmail because in development mode it works.

Not quite sure why my company's account can't receive email from the rails app in production mode on linode. Is it because the email is sent from linode so that my company's email sever ignore emails from these IP addresses? I thought the email is sent by gmail sever instead of linode, is the understanding correct? Is there anyone who might give me a clue what's going wrong here?

paste my production.rb

```
# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxxxx.com' }
#config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
#config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
```

and environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings =
{
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "xxxxx.com",
  :user_name => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
  :password => "xxxxxx",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: have you set up the domain in your config.rb file ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the environment variables? For example in your environment/production.rb there should be something like this.

> config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "yourhost" }

Answer (score 0):

once try to start your application in production mode on your development machine and set in production.rb

`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

then try to send email again.

Comment: I think the problem is not that email is not sent out, but my company's email account can't receive. I tried changing the riase_delivery_errors to true, unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a couple years old, but I figured I would post what worked for me. Here is what I used to send emails from Gmail on my Rails application hosted on my Linode server:

In `config/environments/production.rb`

The first part I missed here was the protocol, set that to `http`:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'HOST_NAME', protocol: 'http' }`

Next and still within `config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"`

Lastly and still within `config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => 'USERNAME@gmail.com',
    :password             => 'PASSWORD',
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }`

If, after those changes, it is still not working, try changing `config/initializers/devise.rb` as follows:

`config.mailer_sender = 'SAME_EMAIL_AS_PRODUCTION@gmail.com'`

Making sure that the email given in `config/initializers/devise.rb` matches the one given in `config/environments/production.rb`.

Hope this helps someone.